# I dont know what to do with errors anymore

Tags: java, error-handling

Hi im still new with coding, and ive making this code for day. it has a lot of error to the point i dont understand it anymore. can you please help with whats wrong with the code and revise it to make it work or run.

here my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class GradeDistribution

 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
  print_header();

    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);

{
    System.out.println("******************************************************");
    System.out.println("This program will present the number of grades" ); //INTRODUCTION
    System.out.println("you input for grades A-F and turn this information"); //TO
    System.out.println("in to a bar graph for ease."); //PROGRAM
    System.out.println("******************************************************");
    System.out.println(" ");


         for(double loopcounter=0; loopcounter<5; loopcounter++)

         {

         switch(loopcounter)

         {


        case 0:  "\nGrade A: |"; break;

        case 1:  "\Grade B: |"; break;

        case 3:  "\Grade C: |"; break;

        case 4:  "\Grade D: |"; break;

        case 5:  "\Grade F: |"; break;

         }


         //loop to output each asterisk

         for(double asteriskcounter=0; asteriskcounter<array[loopcounter]/2; 
asteriskcounter++)

         System.out.println ('*');

         System.out.println("| " << array[loopcounter] << '%');
  }

    percent=100/14; // 7;
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" TOTAL GRADES ENTERED - ");

    char[] line = percent*a/2;//3; Bcent=percent*b/2; Ccent=percent*c/2; Dcent=percent*d/2; 
Ecent=percent*e/2; Fcent=percent*f/2;

    } //end;

    System.out.println(" 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100");
    System.out.println(" | | | | | | | | | | |");
    System.out.println(" **************************************************");

    double array[6] = {Acent, Bcent, Ccent, Dcent, Ecent, Fcent}; //stores grades as 
percentage
    char[] line = array2[6] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'}; //stores letters a-f
    // loop for each grade
    for(double loopcounter=0; loopcounter<6; loopcounter++)
{

    System.out.println(" ");
    // loop to output each asterisk
    for(double asteriskcounter=0; asteriskcounter<array[loopcounter]; asteriskcounter++)
{

       System.out.println("*");
}
    // prdouble the grade after the asterisks
    System.out.prdoubleln( " GRADE "[loopcounter]);
```

please help me again. for i really need it with my assignment and im really having a hard time catching up already.
Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: What's the error that it's showing?

Comment: `double loopcounter` - why a double?

Comment: It seems that you used search & replace over the whole file to replace `int` with `double` - you have loop counters that are double (which doesn't make that much sense) and you have `System.out.prdoubleln()` instead of `System.out.println`.

Comment: The sequence of statements seems messed up: variables are used before they are declared. `System.out.println("| " << array[loopcounter] << '%');` looks like a mix of C++ (where you can use `<<` to append to an output stream) with Java (where you use `System.out.println()` to print text). This line should read `System.out.println("| " + array[loopcounter] + '%');`

Answer (score 1):

You should check parenthesis because some of them are missing.

You do not have a print_header() method in your code, define a method for it.

If you want to get output in switch-case, you should use System.out.print() or System.out.println() methods because you have just written some strings there.

In for loop, you have written "array[loopcounter]", you do not have an array which name is "array" before that loop.

Also, "percent" variable should have a data type.

In below, the array, which name is "array" has some strings (they should have double-quote) but you define this array as a char. You should use String.

The last problem is that "System.out.prdoubleln()" method. System.out does not have this method.

- Use int variable in your loops.

I have checked quickly and have seen these problems.